Mui x-date-picker not working with nextjs14
I'm experiencing an error when trying to pass a function (AdapterDayjs) as a prop to a component in my Next.js application.
The error message is:
Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server". Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

<... dateAdapter={function AdapterDayjs} children=...>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
this is my code
import DashLayout from '@/components/dashLayout'
import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v14-appRouter'

import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs'

export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head></head>

      <body>
        <AppRouterCacheProvider>
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <DashLayout>{children}</DashLayout>
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}



I have created a sandbox here with the packages i'm using: codesandbox
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I resolve this error and pass the AdapterDayjs function as a prop to my component?
I'm expecting the x-date-picker to work normally, so that i can use the DatePicker component in my app

you could wrap this <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>             <DashLayout>{children}</DashLayout>           </LocalizationProvider> in a client side component

To solve this, create another file and put the provider code in it with the 'use client' to make client side component, then wrap your layout code in it.
file path i suggest: /src/lib/DatePickerProvider.tsx
Exemple of the solution:

'use client'

import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs'

interface ClientLocalizationProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export default function ClientLocalizationProvider({
  children
}: ClientLocalizationProviderProps) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      {children}
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}

